# Akka actor traversing large sets of data without blocking

Tags: scala, akka, actor, caffeine

I have a akka actor which read from hazelcast and builds a `Map[id:String, Set[val:String]]`. Now i want to traverse this map and put the following tuple `((id, val))(true)` into Scala caffeine cache (another actor). How can i achieve this without blocking? The map is huge (millions of record)

Comment: What is blocking your code from traversing the dataset ?

Comment: traversing Map and writing to cache takes a lot of time and docker goes OOM with Cluster Node [akka.tcp://rapids@10.2.9.30:2551] - Scheduled sending of heartbeat was delayed. Previous heartbeat was sent [37373] ms ago, expected interval is [5000] ms. This may cause failure detection to mark members as unreachable. The reason can be thread starvation, e.g. by running blocking tasks on the default dispatcher, CPU overload, or GC.

Comment: The fact that you're ooming and having thread starvation while running in a docker container indicates to me that GC (and its interaction with running in a docker container allocated with far less than all of the host CPUs) is the problem more than blocking.

Comment: @nocturnal did you ever figure this out? I'm having same issue outside of docker.